# How to convert this SQL to LINQ of ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this SQL statement:

```
select 
    table1.DIRECTORATE_ID, 
    table2.PLA_NAME + '//' + table1.ENGLISH_DIRECTORATE_CODE as EngCode
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.PLA_ID = table2.PLA_ID order by EngCode
```

I need to do the same type of query in my EF code that gives me a `List<>`. Something like this:

```
var query = (from t1 table1.DIRECTORATE_ID, table2.PLA_NAME + '//' + table1.ENGLISH_DIRECTORATE_CODE as EngCode
             from table1
             inner join table2 on table1.PLA_ID = table2.PLA_ID order by EngCode)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, this is ASP.net EF. C#

Comment: You've got column definitions (the `select` clause) in your `from` clause in your c# example.

Comment: try either http://www.sqltolinq.com or https://www.linqpad.net

Comment: Thank you, Jayesh, they are good resources, hopefully, I can get the answer from there without needing to post a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got column references in your `from` clause. In SQL, the order is (in this particular example)

1. select
2. from
3. join
4. order by

In LINQ, the order is

1. from
2. join
3. orderby
4. select

You can write this in Query Syntax

```
var query = from t1 in table1
            join t2 in table2 on t1.PLA_ID equals t2.PLA_ID
            let EngCode = t2.PLA_NAME + "//" + t1.ENGLISH_DIRECTORATE_CODE
            orderby EngCode
            select new 
            { 
                t1.DIRECTORATE_ID, 
                EngCode
            }

var data = query.ToList();
```

Or with extension methods

```
var data = table1
    .Join(
        table2,
        t1 => t1.PLA_ID,
        t2 => t2.PLA_ID,
        (t1, t2) => new 
        { 
            t1.DIRECTORATE_ID, 
            EngCode = t2.PLA_NAME + "//" + t1.ENGLISH_DIRECTORATE_CODE 
        })
    .OrderBy(x => x.EngCode)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Gunr2171, thank you so much for your help, much appreciated!!! I'll try it tomorrow and let you know then.

Comment: Hi Gunr2171, the original has "order by EngCode", but I don't see this in your codes? is your codes ordered by EngCode?

Comment: whoops, let me add that in

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it tomorrow morning and let you know the result. much appreciated!!!